# What is & and * operators in docker-compose syntax and how to use them?

Tags: docker-compose

I noticed that the docker-compose.yml file of a project contains syntax such as `&id001` and `*id001`, `&id002` and `*id002` in various services. For example:

```
version: '2.3'
services:
  nlp-servlet:

    ...some configs ...

    logging: &id001
      driver: json-file
      options:
        max-file: '10'
        max-size: 10m

  consul:
      ... some config ...
    logging: *id001

  redir:
       ... some config ...
    volumes:
      - redir_log:/usr/src/app/log
    logging: *id001

  tbgas-db:
     ... some config ...
     volumes:
        - tbgas_db:/var/lib/mysql
     logging: *id001

volumes:
  logdir: &id002
    driver: local
  redir_log: *id002
  tbgas_db: *id002
```

I can kind of guess how `id001` and `id002` work, and I think they work a bit differently. Is that accurate?

Also, where can I find some documentation about this type of syntax? What are they called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are [YAML anchors](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2765878): the & declares it as an anchor, and the * references it, being replaced by the actual contents in the anchor. You can see more examples of its usage in [this section](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extension-fields) of the compose file reference.

I would consider moving these into extension fields if possible, and giving them descriptive names to avoid confusion.